# change the value of session variable

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I have created a website in which when user logs in he specifies the year i.e. 2013-2014, or 2014-2015, and so on...Now, I am storing this value of year in a session variable which I am using it through out the site. Now, if user wants to change the year he will have to sign out and then log in with different year. I have created a dropdown menu on home page which will show all the years from database. I want to change the value of the session variable by selecting a year from home page without signing out.

Here is the code:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["myusername"])){
    header("location:login.php");
}

$year = $_SESSION["year"];
```

Here is the code for dropdown menu:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM year";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<select class='innerinputstyle' id='year' name='year'><option value='$year'>$year</option>";
while($note=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value=$note[year]>$note[year]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Can anyone please tell me how to change the value of `$year` from home page?

Comment: for this select you can add an ajax call for onselect event. that ajax call can trigger a php file which simply change the $_SESSION['year'] to the passed value.

Comment: how could you do that? i mean let's say i put a button and then on submit i GET the value on another php file. But how do i change the session variable? can you give me an example code or reference?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo "<select class='innerinputstyle' id='year' name='year'>"
```

into

```
echo "<select class='innerinputstyle' id='year' name='year' onChange='doIt()'>"
```

and here is the ajax function

```
function doIt(){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    }
    var new_year = document.getElementById('year').value;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","change_year.php?year="+new_year,true);
    xmlhttp.send()
    return false;
}
```

on change_year.php you can easily change

```
$_SESSION['year']=$_GET['year'];
```

Warning: Untested code. Used to sketch the idea.

Comment: hey i tried this by submitting the form. but when i am redirecting it back to home page, the value remains the same.

Comment: do you set the value of $_SESSION['year'] on your homepage? note that when you're using ajax technique you don't need to submit the form. On selecting an option the doIt() function will be triggered.

Comment: i tried doing it with ajax. but it's giving me an error on this line. `xmlhttp.open("GET","change_year.php?year"=,true);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have plenty of choices to achieve this, and the AJAX one is one of them , but everything depends on how you want to implement the user interface. You can think to create a little form with the drop down and submit the year, you can do this via a submit button or via javascript and as for the AJAX example the solution is always the same:

```
$_SESSION['year']=$_GET['year'];
```

At the end depend all on the user interface, if you want it invisible to the user, without refreshing the page, use AJAX, otherwise just submit your input

Comment: hey i tried this by submitting the form. but when i am redirecting it back to home page, the value remains the same.

Comment: Where are you posting your form to? Which page? I guess you're posting to tje himepage itself, then you should have something like:himepage

Comment: session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION["myusername"])){ header("location:login.php"); }  $_SESSION['year']=$_GET['year']; $year = $_SESSION["year"];